# Triangle inequality for infinite number of terms

Tags: real-analysis

We can prove that for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have triangle inequality: $$|x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n|\leqslant |x_1|+|x_2|+\cdots+|x_n|.$$

How to prove it for series i.e. $$\left|\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\right|\leqslant \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|.$$
Can anyone help to me with this?

Comment: where is it you get stuck?

Comment: You need more conditions, e.g. the inequality doesn't make sense if either $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ or $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|$ diverges.

Comment: @user236182 The divergence of $\sum \lvert a_n\rvert$ is harmless, we have an obvious (and correct) interpretation then, provided $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: Write each series as a limit of partial sums. If the inequality holds for each partial sum, it must hold in the limit.

Comment: @user236182 can you give a whole claim with proof?

Comment: We still need $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ to converge.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|<\infty. $
For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have triangle inequality: $$|a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n|\leqslant |a_1|+|a_2|+\cdots+|a_n|\leq \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n| .$$
This implies $\left|\sum \limits_{j=1}^{n}a_j\right|\leqslant \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Letting $n\to\infty$ in the last inequality and using continuity of modulus function, we get
$$\left|\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\right|\leqslant \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|.$$

If $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|=\infty$ then inequality is true.

Comment: What do you mean by "If $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|=\infty$ then inequality is true."? If $a_n=1$, shouldn't we have equality?

Comment: $a=b\implies a\le b$

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case the easiest way is to show it via contradiction. Let's assume assume that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converge.

Now, we assume $\Big|\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\Big|>\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|$ and therfore we define $\epsilon:=\Big|\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\Big|-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|>0$ . Then, by definition of convergence there exists an index $m_0$ such that for all $m>m_0$ we have $\Big|\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m}a_n\Big|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\implies \Big|\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m}a_n\Big|>\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|\geq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{m}|a_n|$, which contradicts triangle inequality. Note that if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|=\infty$ then we get a contradiction immediately.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different proof for the case $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|< \infty $ (i.e., $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is absolutely convergent):

First, we show that $\lim_{N \to \infty} |\sum_{n=1}^N a_n| = | \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n|$.

Denote the $N$th partial sum by $s_N := \sum_{n=1}^N a_n$.
The absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ implies ordinary convergence, so there exists $L \in \mathbb{R}$, s.t. $L = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n := \lim_{N\to \infty} s_N $. Then by [this exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667084/proving-that-x-n-to-l-implies-x-n-to-l-and-what-about-the-converse), the absolute value of $s_N$ also converges to the absolute value of $L$, i.e.,  $\lim_{N\to \infty} |s_N| = |L| = | \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n|$ .

Finally, $\forall N, |s_N| = |\sum_{n=1}^N a_n|\leq \sum_{n=1}^N |a_n| $ (by finite triangle inequality). Taking $\lim_{N\to \infty}$ on both sides gives the desired result.