# Absolute value of limit can be taken outside

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

We have a sequence of functions $f_n$ that converge to $f$.

As part of a proof I am writing, if I can prove that

$$|f(x) - f(y)| = \lim_{n \to \infty}|f_n(x) - f_n(y)|$$

then I am done. Proving this requires me to show that

$$|\lim (f_n(x) - f_n(y)) | = \lim |f_n(x) - f_n(y)|$$

and I'm not sure how I can do that. I found this answer [limit of absolute value of something equals absolute value of limit of something?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463375/limit-of-absolute-value-of-something-equals-absolute-value-of-limit-of-something) which says it exists by 'continuity of absolute value' although I am not sure how that justifies it. Could someone elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We note that if $x_n \to x$ and $g$ is continuous, then:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} g(x_n) = g\left(\lim_{x \to \infty} x_n\right)
$$
i.e. the limit and the function can be interchanged. The absolute value function $x \mapsto |x|$ is continuous. Therefore, in your case we have:
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - f(y)| &= \left|\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)\right) - \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(y)\right)\right| \\
&= \left|\lim_{n \to \infty} (f_n(x) - f_n(y))\right| \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n(x) - f_n(y)|
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to make sure, the "note that" statement follows from definition of continuity right?

Comment: @a6623 There are many different definitions of continuity, but that statement is a simple consequence of most of these definitions anyway.